# Google Maps Custom Nightmode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, uiview, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to use the **google maps api** so that I can view the world in a **daylight mode/nighttime mode** in realtime depending on sunrise/sunset when the user zooms in on a certain region.

I have yet to have any luck, and would really appreciate any advice/tips!

Answer (score 1):

As of right now, Google Maps for iOS SDK nighttime mode is not a feature.

You can track its progress over issue [tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5661&q=apitype%3AIosSDK&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Internal%20Stars).